# Load a Query in PFQueryTableViewController using segue information Parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform, pfquery

I was looking for this in a while and didn't find anything about it. I want to build a table using the `PFQueryTableViewController`, but some informations in my Query to build this table are passed by segue in the previous `ViewController`. The problem is the program load the `Query` before get the information on the segue, so the `Query` results in a null search every time.

That's my segue in the first `ViewController`:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"vai"]) {
      NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    yTableViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

locallabel = [object objectForKey:@"local"];

destViewController.lugar = locallabel;

}
```

and this is my `Query` in the next View, which is the `PFQueryTableViewController`:

```
@interface yTableViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableIndexSet *optionIndices;
@end

@implementation yTableViewController

@synthesize segint;

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
    if (self) {
    // Custom the table

    // The className to query on
    self.parseClassName = @"Pedidos";

   // self.parseClassName = @"Locais";

    // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style
    self.textKey = @"local";

    // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

    // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
    self.paginationEnabled = YES;

    // The number of objects to show per page
    self.objectsPerPage = 10;
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {

    // Custom initialization
    }
return self;
}



// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
// self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
{
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
[query whereKey:@"local" equalTo:lugar]; //this is the problem of everything, when i try to find some items where the key @"local" is equal to an NSString defined in the previous PFQueryTableVC and passed from segue


if (self.objects.count == 0) {
    query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
}

[query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];


   if ([self.objects count] == 0) {
 query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
 }

//    [query orderByAscending:@"name"];

return query;
}
```

How can I load the segue before the program build the Query to mount the Table?

PS. I already tried to do a `perfomseguewithidentifier` in the `DidselectrowatindexPath` method, but I think that the problem is not how I am sending the information, but the time I am retrieving it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see [query findObjects:] getting called anywhere. Right now your query does nothing. Also your issue might be that you are loading data into the table before query can come back with the result. Can you post the code of how/when you are loading data into the table?

Comment: the Query method is placed correctly, unfortunately. I will post the entire code in 5 secs so you can take a look! thank you for your reply!

Comment: o just posted the entire code of the second view, witch is the PFQueryTableVC. If you look the (void)QueryforTable method, you will see that the problem is that the NSString *lugar is not yet loaded from segue when the query is perfumed.

Comment: What is "lugar" object type in your case on the ViewController that you are segueing to? If it is an outlet than this won't work you'll have to pass data via public property or something. One thing I can tell you for sure is that your prepareForSegueMethod: is getting called before your following ViewController is calling any methods at all.

Comment: I dont think it is, becouse in the debug control i put an NSLog to show the value of Lugar in the VIewdidLoad method and the NSLog is pointed after the query, with the app crashing bafore shows any log Lugar is a NSString defined in the previous VC, as you can see in the prepareforsegue method

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to ask - if you are setting any outlets for a viewcontroller you are segueing to in your preparForSegue: method than it won't work because none of your destinationVC's outlets are set yet. What is your exception description?

Comment: Itã not an outlet, its a variable of string type. Do you know any way i can load It bafore the PFQuery?

Comment: I would love to help you, but I still don't fully understand what is the issue. None of the methods of your yTableViewController are getting called before prepareForSegue: is executed -- guaranteed (as long as you don't set any variable on destinationVC from the background thread which I don't see in your code). Try NSLog your lugar variable in the VC you are segueing (at end of prepareForSegue:) from see if you set it properly and if it is indeed an NSSring or whatever the type you are expecting.

Comment: ITGronk!! Can you believe that the only problem was that i was not synthesizing the variable "Local" in the PFTableViewController.m!? After doing that, the value was passed corrected! Thank you so much for your Help. Your faith in the fact the the yTableViewController was actually getting called before the segue made me look into the code again over again to discover that!! Thank you again!!